# Solution to recurrence relation with two variables: one variable known in advance from data

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I want to solve the following recurrence relation:

$$a_{n+1} = \alpha a_n + c_{n+1}$$

with initial conditions:
$$ a_0 = 0$$
$$ c_1 = \beta$$

I actually know $c_{n+1}$ from the data in advance, however I am trying to find a solution to $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $c_{n+1}$. Is this possible?

Comment: Just to clarify, $\alpha$ and $c_n$ are known? Also, what have you tried yourself to solve this problem?

Comment: @B.Mehta Yes, but I wrote $c_n$ with a subscript because its values are changing. Also, $\beta$ is known, just to be completely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep using the formula and get a pattern like this:
$a_{n+1} = \alpha a_n + c_{n+1} = \alpha(\alpha a_{n-1} + c_{n})+ c_{n+1} = \alpha(\alpha(\alpha a_{n-2} + c_{n-1})+c_n)+ c_{n+1} = \cdots = \alpha^{n+1}a_0 + \alpha^nc_1 + \alpha^{n-1}c_2+ \cdots \alpha c_n + c_{n+1}$

---

If you want in terms of cumulative sum

$a_{n+1} = \alpha a_n + c_{n+1}$
$a_{n} = \alpha a_{n-1} + c_{n}$
$a_{n-1} = \alpha a_{n-2} + c_{n-1}$
$\cdot  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \cdot \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \cdot  $
$\cdot  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \cdot \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \cdot  $
$\cdot  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \cdot \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \cdot  $
$a_2 = \alpha a_1 + c_2$
$a_1 = \alpha a_0 + c_1$
 Adding

---

$a_{n+1} = (\alpha -1)\sum_{k=0}^n a_k + \sum_{k=1}^n c_k$

Comment: Thanks. Can you express it terms of a cummulative sum of $c_n$?

Comment: To be clearer, by cummulative sum, I mean the following: `http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CumulativeSum.html`, and we denote the cummulative sum up to index $n$ by $\sigma c_n$

Comment: @kolonel check if the edited answer is in the correct form

Comment: I think it should just $\alpha$ in the last expression not $\alpha - 1$.

Comment: by adding we get, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k = \alpha \sum_{k=0}^n a_k + \sum_{k=1}^n c_k \implies a_{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k = \alpha \sum_{k=0}^n a_k + \sum_{k=1}^n c_k$$